# NullPointerException I don't understand

Tags: nullpointerexception

I'm a junior java programmer and I get this exception when running my program which is too long to post here can someone explain this stack trace...Thank You!

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.getMinimumSpan(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.getMinimumSpan(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.getMinimumSpan(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getScrollableTracksViewportWidth(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Post relevant parts. No one on earth can know what's happening in your program if he doesn't see it.

Comment: Don't know which part I should paste cause I don't know where or why I'm getting an nullpointerexception it doesn't say from which line

Comment: Is this the complete exception? Copy the entire thing from the console.

Comment: If you are using an IDE, make sure line numbers are visible, use try catch with printStackTrace(). It should point you to the possible cause of exception